# How can I use kubectl commands on my cluster hosted on ec2 instances from my local machine without ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, networking, amazon-ec2, kubectl

I want to be able to use `kubectl` commands on my master ec2 instance from my local machine without ssh. I tried copying `.kube` into my local but the problem is that my `kubeconfig` is using the private network and so when i try to run `kubectl` from my local I can not connect.

Here is what I tried:

```
user@somehost:~/aws$ scp -r -i some-key.pem ubuntu@some.ip.0.0:.kube/ . 

user@somehost:~/aws$ cp -r .kube $HOME/

user@somehost:~/aws$ kubectl version
```

and I got:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp some.other.ip.0:6443: i/o timeout
```

Is there a way to change the `kubeconfig` in a way that would tell my `kubectl` when I run commands from local to run them on the master on the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `clusters.cluster.server` key in your kubectl config with externally accessible IP.
For this your VM with master node must have external IP assigned.

Depending on how you provisioned your cluster, you may need to [add additional name to Kubernetes API server certificate](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/07/30/adding-a-name-to-kubernetes-api-server-certificate/)

With `kubeadm` you can just reset cluster with

```
kubeadm reset
```

on all nodes (including master), and then

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<master external IP>
```

---

Alternatively you can issue your commands with `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag. E.g.

```
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify get pods
```